# Adding Android views together

Tags: xamarin.android

Under iOS, I can have something like this

```
var myButton = new UIButton(new RectangleF(4,4,100,42));
var myTextView = new UITextView
{
    Text = "Hello",
    Frame = new RectangleF(4,4,42,21)
};
myButton.Add(myTextView);
```

this allows me to add a `UITextView` to a `UIButton`. Very quick and very simple.

Is there something similar that allows me to do something similar on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if the type of the view is `ViewGroup`, otherwise no.

You can overlay views, i.e. when they are both inside of a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

A short list of `ViewGroup` type of views I can remember are:

- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
- FrameLayout
- GridLayout
- CardView

Other special views (limited number of nested views)

- DrawerLayout
- SlidingPaneLayout

List type of views

- ListView
- RecyclerView
- Spinner

In short what you want is not possible with the two views you gave as an example. However, it is entirely possible to change the look of those views to your liking.